# How can I call a function in a router from a module in fastapi?

Tags: python, fastapi

For example, I have an endpoint and I need to call the test function in it according to the schedule for execution.

```
@router.get('/test')
def test():
    print('Hello')
```

[image: example from the debugger when the function gets called]

Comment: Are you asking how you can call this endpoint on a schedule (i.e. the endpoint gets invoked at for example 13:15, 14:15, 15:15, etc.), or how you can call a function in a module from inside your `test` function, instead of calling `print`?

Comment: Thx.
Found another solution.
@repeat_every decorator
The functionality was enough to solve the problems.